# How to make sure data retrieved from MySQL is UTF8 for json_encode in PHP?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am converting SQL table rows into JSON, with the help of PHP, MySQLi and json_encode.

My present code approach is -

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_GET['from'])) {
  $from = $_GET['from'] - 1;
} else {
  $from = 0;
}

if(isset($_GET['count'])) {
  $count = $_GET['count'];
} else {
  $count = 10000;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` Limit $from, $count";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $resultArray = array();
  $tempArray = array();

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $tempArray = $row;
      array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
  }
  //var_dump($resultArray);
  $json = json_encode($resultArray);
} else {
    $json = '{"Json_Result":"Record NOT found!"}';
}
print($json);
$conn->close();
```

This works fine, if the data retrieved from table is in correct format. But, unfortunately some of my rows contain some special characters, which were not converted into proper format at the inserting. This code fails if it encounters any of such rows. On using `var_dump`, I found that those special characters are seen as `�`.
On searching about issue, I found out that, for `json_encode` to be working, all characters must be in `utf8` format. But, I am unable to figure out, how should I implement it here, before using `json_encode`?

Comment: Did you add  `SET NAMES UTF8` for your mysql connection?

Comment: @krasipenkov Where/How to do that?

Comment: `if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'UTF8');`

Comment: try this mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'UTF8');
    $json = json_encode($resultArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: @krasipenkov but how should I use `SET NAMES UTF8` after connection? I mean should I write `$conn->SET NAMES UTF8` or something else?

Comment: @krasipenkov sorry I just saw the 2nd line in your comment, testing it now

Comment: right after the IF statement do `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'UTF8');`

Comment: @krasipenkov I don't why it's still not displaying anything. But when I use var_dump it shows everything.

Comment: @MoinulIslam your solution works